# Read a file either with mmap or fscanf in C

Tags: c, mmap, scanf

I'm asking both an advice and an opinion

I have a file made of couples on integers, for example

```
1 2
1 3
4 7
2 5
3 10
```

Now, I want to read it, but every method I can think of, has his own problems.

Using the mmap() function, it returns a string of character, but extracting the numbers from it seems very painful, since I don't know their lenghts, so the use atoi() or the classic Number-'0' seems not to be enough.

On the other hand, the use of fscanf gives me directly the numbers in their integer form, but I always have issues on its termination. How do you know when it has finished reading? Does it return '\0' or EOF or something else? By experience, it seems to me that it behaves randomly.. It could be useful to use a function that counts the number of lines of a file, but does that even exist?

Now, to you. Which method would you prefer to use? And how would you fix the problems above?

Comment: `while(2==fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &v1, &v2)){//do stuff }`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I thought something similar, but I don't know what fscanf does return.. 0?

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be well stuctured? If yes you can use `fscanf` return value. But if some how someone will input 3 numbers instead of two, or eat a space you will be in trouble and need to use some validation.

Comment: @luk32 I can test the sequence int-space-int-changeline, so it's not really a problem. what's scanf return value for errors?

Comment: @Exodd Man, knowledge lies around: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). It should be consistent with plain c compiler.

Comment: @Exodd fscanf also returns 0 or EOF. It seems it's enough with it so is that if you returned this case 2 that was able to read two successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) is very easy. `fscanf` returns the number of items successfully scanned. So in your case you can use:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&int1,&int2)==2)
{ 
// successfully scanned 2 integers
}
```

Where `fp` is a file pointer and `int1` and `int2` are variables of type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strtol`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) to convert the numbers from your `mmap()`ped buffer and a line you've read via traditional I/O alike.  I find it very convenient (in fact, even more convenient than `fscanf` under most circumstances).  If you want to find the next newline in your buffer, carefully(!) using [`memchr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memchr.3.html) is a very efficient way of doing so.  It can then give you the next pointer to pass to `strtol`.

If you want generality, you should take precautions that not every file can be `mmap()`ped (eg pipes).  Therefore, a robust program should try to `mmap()` the file and if that fails, fall back to traditional I/O.

Answer (score 1):

`mmap()` with an ad-hoc parser is as fast as possible, even if it isn't very flexible. The below will parse files of the form you gave *and perhaps no other*, but if it were mechanically generated that might be ok:

```
char*p,*e,*x;
int m,n;
x=mmap(...); /* e=end of buffer; */
for(m=n=0,p=x;p<e;++p){
  if(*p==' '){m=n;n=0;}
  else if(*p=='\n'){emit(m,n);m=n=0;}
  else{n*=10;n+=*p-'0';}}
```

A better file format (binary) is faster still.

---

Regarding your second question: *how do I know when fscanf() is at EOF?*. That's what `feof(fp)` does. You want something like:

```
while(feof(fp)&&2==fscanf(fp,"%d %d\n",&m,&n))emit(m,n);
```

but beware: This is *much* slower than the above, and not much more robust. How much slower? On my mid-2012 MBA I'll get around 600mbps, while using `fscanf` I'll be lucky to get 10mbps.

Comment: I didn't really want to reconstruct the numbers digitwise, but yes, that works too, thanks.

Comment: What do you think `atoi()` or `strtol()` do? What do you think `fscanf()` is doing when it scans the pattern and sees `%d`?